# HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, database-connection, hikaricp

I'm facing this issue i do deployment through jenkins.Our project is a multiTenant project which follows (Single database & Separate Schemas).

Total 4 microservice we have and same tenantdatasource.java ,hibernateConfig.java in all microservice we have kept, along with same hikari pool config in application.properties.

Whenever i do deployment it runs fine till 1 day and next day our api's starts giving error.
connection getting lost after 30000ms , it says Hikari Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.But runs fine in local.

```
2022-09-07 10:34:17.050 DEBUG 304980 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=4)
2022-09-07 10:34:17.050 DEBUG 304980 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
2022-09-07 10:34:26.421 DEBUG 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-8] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=3)
2022-09-07 10:34:26.422  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-8] c.m.s.tenant.TenantConnectionProvider    : Inside catch for get any conncetion org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
2022-09-07 10:34:26.422  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-8] c.m.session.tenant.RequestInterceptor    : java.lang.NullPointerException
2022-09-07 10:34:26.422  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-8] c.m.session.tenant.TenantSchemaResolver  : TenantSchemaResolver: qa-tenant-1
2022-09-07 10:34:26.423  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-8] c.m.s.tenant.TenantConnectionProvider    : INSIDE GET CONNECTION
2022-09-07 10:34:26.423  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-8] c.m.s.tenant.TenantConnectionProvider    : INSIDE GET ANY CONNECTION
2022-09-07 10:34:26.423 DEBUG 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=3)
2022-09-07 10:34:26.423  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-3] c.m.s.tenant.TenantConnectionProvider    : Inside catch for get any conncetion org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.
2022-09-07 10:34:26.424  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-3] c.m.session.tenant.RequestInterceptor    : java.lang.NullPointerException
2022-09-07 10:34:26.424  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-3] c.m.session.tenant.TenantSchemaResolver  : TenantSchemaResolver: qa-tenant-1
2022-09-07 10:34:26.424  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-3] c.m.s.tenant.TenantConnectionProvider    : INSIDE GET CONNECTION
2022-09-07 10:34:26.424  INFO 304980 --- [http-nio-9091-exec-3] c.m.s.tenant.TenantConnectionProvider    : INSIDE GET ANY CONNECTION
2022-09-07 10:34:30.005 DEBUG 304980 --- [MessageBroker-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=2)
2022-09-07 10:34:30.005 DEBUG 304980 --- [MessageBroker-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=3)
2022-09-07 10:34:30.005  INFO 304980 --- [MessageBroker-2] c.m.s.tenant.TenantConnectionProvider    : Inside catch for get any conncetion org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30004ms.
2022-09-07 10:34:30.005  INFO 304980 --- [MessageBroker-1] c.m.s.tenant.TenantConnectionProvider    : Inside catch for get any conncetion org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-
```

Hikari config

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=180000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =true
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=40000

logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG 
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE
```

HibernateConfig.java

```
import org.hibernate.MultiTenancyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class HibernateConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource,
            TenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
            TenantSchemaResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl,
            JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {

        Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap<>(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, false);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.meis.*");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);
        return em;
    }
}
```

TenantConnectionProvider.java

```
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Component
public class TenantConnectionProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    private final DataSource datasource;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantConnectionProvider.class);

    @Value("${master.schema.name}")
    public String defaultTenant;

    public TenantConnectionProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.datasource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return datasource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

        try {
            connection.close();

            logger.info("Connection closed");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Connection not closed", e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
//        log.debug("Get connection for tenant {}", tenantIdentifier);
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();

        connection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
        connection.setCatalog(tenantIdentifier);
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
//        log.debug("Release connection for tenant {}", tenantIdentifier);
        connection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
        connection.setCatalog(tenantIdentifier);
        releaseAnyConnection(connection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class aClass) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> aClass) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
server.port=9091
spring.profiles.active=qa
logging.file.name=/home/ubuntu/logs/session-app.log
logging.file.max-size=10MB
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR
## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB


spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

admin.default.topic=admin

byPassToken=hhhkhguuyiiih786566bhhkhgjbnkhgxfcgvhjghfgfvkhhhgcvhgfvbnbvbvvcdfdzzxknnlkbj



# Connection pool configuration

spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=180000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=40000



logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG 
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE
```

Comment: Your `HibernateConfig` should be an `@Configuration` not an `@Component`. Why is `auto-commit` set to `true`? You should have some form of transaction management. Can you add your jpa properties (from the `application.properties`) to your question as well. Generally these errors come from wrong configuration or from manually using the `DataSource` and obtaining connections without properly releasing them.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for yours reply, we have given @Transactional to some of our heavy CRUD ServiceImpl and also given @Configuration to HibernateConfig.

    Only this much Jpa Prop we have given
```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: All uour methods operating on the database should be `@Transactional`. Please don't add additional information as comments as that is totally unreadable. Please add your `applicaiton.properties` to your question instead.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum i have added application.properties file. Thank You.

Comment: As you are using Spring Boot I would suggest removing your dedicated configuration and add a `EntityManagerFactoryBuilderCustomizer` to configure the multi-tenant stuff, that way you can use the Spring Boot auto configuration better. However you have a connection leak so check the places in which you use the entitymanager without a transaction (It shouls really be transactional all your database related stuff) and see if you are properly using it. Also check if there are places you are using a connection without properly returning it.